# Intersection of context-free language and its reversal

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I know that intersection of two context-free languages is not always context-free and the following problem:

> Given two context-free languages A and B, is $A \bigcap B \neq \emptyset$ ?

is undecidable. But is that true in particular case when we know that $B = \{ w^{R} | w \in A \}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ contains a  palindromic string $w$ then $w^R=w$. So in this case, $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$. But if $A$ doesn't contain any palindromic string, we cannot find a common element of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: That's what I know, but language of palindromic strings is not regular. Is there an algorithm to to check if A contains a palindromic string? I think there's not, but I can't prove it.